# Knockout JS Setting Initial value for dropdown from observable array object property value

Tags: knockout.js, binding

I am creating a meeting attendance manager, and the information is being saved into our db. I have a drop down select list on my sign in form called "Attendee Type" which contains values that are populated from an observable array called attendeeTypes. Attendee types is filled with objects in the form 

{Id:1, Name: "Parent"}
{Id:2, Name: "Staff"}, etc.

Now, the rows in my table are also dynamically created by running a foreach over an observable array, meetingAttendees.
**Meeting Attendees**
`self.meetingAttendees = ko.observableArray([{ AttendeeTypeId: ko.observable(1),<br> AttendeeNames: ko.observableArray([{ Name: "Marlin" }, { Name: "Dory" }]),<br> AttendeeSiteNumber: ko.observable(40), <br>StudentNames: ko.observableArray([{ Name: "P. Sherman" }, { Name: "42 Wallaby Way" }, { Name: "Sydney" }]), <br>Email: ko.observable("test@test.com"), <br>Telephone: ko.observable("559-222-5555") }`
As you  can see, each row in the table has an attendeeTypeId in it. If this value is pre-populated, like it is here, I would like the dropdown to switch to the appropriate value. This will be helpful in preserving data in case a refresh happens.

My Html:
`<table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="attendeeTypeCol">Attendee Type</th>
                        <th class="attendeeNameCol">Attendee Name(s)</th>
                        <th class="schoolNameCol">School Name</th>
                        <th class="studentNameCol">Student Name</th>
                        <th class="emailCol">E-Mail Address</th>
                        <th class="telephoneCol">Telephone Number</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.meetingAttendees">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="attendeeTypeCol">
                            <select style="margin-right: 15px;" data-bind="options: $root.attendeeTypes, optionsText: 'Name',value: $root.meetingAttendees()[$index()].AttendeeTypeId,optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'I am a(n)...'">
                            </select>
                            <span data-bind="text:$index()"></span>
                            <span data-bind="text:$root.meetingAttendees()[$index()].AttendeeTypeId()"></span>
                        </td>
                       ...
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>`

I have two debugging spans so that I can always see the value of $root.meetingAttendees()[$index()].AttendeeTypeId(). When I select a value from the dropdown list, the value does update and change accordingly, so I'm confident it is looking in the right location, but on initial load the value binding is not setting the drop down list to the appropriate option. It is actually setting the the variable to the default 'undefined'.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get the dropdown to set to the appropriate value from the Id in $root.meetingAttendees()[$index()].AttendeeTypeId()?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue on a simpler fiddler here https://jsfiddle.net/y51r3x9g/1/ ... can you see if you can reproduce it there?

Comment: I've updated that fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/y51r3x9g/5/

Here, it is working. But I've left my entire JS there as well. I'm thinking there may be a race condition occuring?

Also, I am on Knockout 3.3.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: After further debugging, I have gotten it found the source of the problem. It is my ajax call self.getAttendeeTypes. It doesn't like me emptying out and reinserting the values. It messes up the binding somehow. So I guess that's where the solution lies

Comment: So it seems that I've solved my own problem. Yes, the view was binding to the viewmodel before my ajax call was done. To remedy this, I didn't apply bindings until after the ajax call was done. While that in itself may have other implications, it seems that this binding on the select list is touchy, and it works for now

Comment: Yes, be careful with binding order when binding lists and the bound values - I've tripped over it as well. The list must be filled _before_ the value is bound. If not, and the list is empty, then the value gets set to *undefined*. There are many different ways to address this - it depends on whether the list is static or dynamic. For static lists you can inject the values into HTML if this is possible. If a dynamic list, one approach is to pass the values in the same AJAX call as the model data, so the viewmodel has both lists and data at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is what was said in the comments.

Credit to Quango for verifying.

For the knockout bound select list, the list must be populated before bindings are applied.

My AJAX call had not completed prior to binding, thus my list bound observable was being set to the default value of "undefined".

By wrapping my binding in a function and calling this function once the AJAX call was done using $.ajax({}).done(--call function--), this guaranteed that the list would be populated before the bindings were applied.

As Quango stated, if a list is static, it's probably best to inject the options in the HTML, but this is useful for dynamically loaded lists.

> "Yes, be careful with binding order when binding lists and the bound values - I've tripped over it as well. The list must be filled before the value is bound. If not, and the list is empty, then the value gets set to undefined. There are many different ways to address this - it depends on whether the list is static or dynamic. For static lists you can inject the values into HTML if this is possible. If a dynamic list, one approach is to pass the values in the same AJAX call as the model data, so the viewmodel has both lists and data at the same time." – Quango